# Sum "Amount" from one table and display in Another Table

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

i have two tables named:

tblPatientBill,
[image]

tblPatientBillDetails

[image]

what i want to do is in tblPatientBill for ID "66" there are two records in tblPatientBillDetail. from the second table i want to add the amount values and display in the main table as total sum value using linq for which i am doing something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(PatientViewModel model)
            {
               List<tblPatientBillDetail> lst = new List<tblPatientBillDetail>();
               tblPatientBill tmp = new tblPatientBill();

               tmp = db.tblPatientBill.Where(x=>x.ID == PatientBillID && x.is_active == true).ToList();


                        lst = db.tblPatientBillDetails.Where(x=>x.PatientBillID == PatientBillID && x.is_active == true).ToList();

                        foreach (var test in lst)
                        {

                            model.Amount += lst.Amount;
                        }
                        Session["templist"] = lst;
}
```

and then give this session value to tblPatientBill table's amount column.

This is my PatientViewModel:

```
public class PatientViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PatientBillID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> is_active { get; set; }
    }
```

tblPatientBillDetail:

```
   public partial class tblPatientBillDetail
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PatientBillID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> is_active { get; set; }

        public virtual tblPatientBill tblPatientBill { get; set; }
    }
```

tblPatientBill:

```
  public partial class tblPatientBill
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblPatientBill()
        {
            this.tblPatientBillDetails = new HashSet<tblPatientBillDetail>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PatientAppointmentID { get; set; }
        public string BillNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Discount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> is_active { get; set; }

        public virtual tblPatientAppointment tblPatientAppointment { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<tblPatientBillDetail> tblPatientBillDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i achieve this using linq.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for specific PatientBill

```
var tblPatientBill = db.tblPatientBill.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == PatientBillID && x.is_active == true);

if (tblPatientBill != null) {
    var lst = db.tblPatientBillDetails
          .Where(x=>x.ID == PatientBillID && x.is_active == true)
          .ToList();


    tblPatientBill.Amount = lst.Select(c => c.Amount).Sum();
}
```

for all Patientbill

```
var tblPatientBills = db.tblPatientBill.Where(x=> x.is_active == true).ToList();

if (tblPatientBills.Count != 0) {
    var lst = db.tblPatientBillDetails
          .Where(x=>x.PatientBillID == PatientBillID && x.is_active == true)
          .ToList();

    foreach(var patientBill in tblPatientBills)
    {
        patientBill.Amount = lst.Where(b => b.PatientBillId == PatientBillID).Select(c => c.Amount).Sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "tblPbill" in it?

Comment: @sadia shortened for `tblPatientBills`. its just the variable you will assign the main table with. It could be `x, y...` any word you will associate it with.

Comment: It is giving error at the following statement .Where(x=>x.PatientBillId == PatientBillID) it is not recognizing "PatientBillID" after the equality signs. and giving error on "DTO"

Comment: @sadia ohh, the `PatientBillId` is the user input for the id. in your example it is 66. Also the DTO is just a class name that will contain the properties you want to show.

Comment: @sadia ill explain further

Comment: i have made few changes let me try with it

Comment: @sadia no worries, drop a comment if still not working

Comment: @sadie dont forget to mark it as an answer if it did help you, thanks